# hibernate update instead of throwing expected error after save

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My code works well but shouldn't according to what I know about Hibernate.

I'm performing a save operation on a object as following:

```
    IProfile profile = profileManager.getById(profileDtoModifyForm.getId());


    profile.setName(profileDtoModifyForm.getName());
    profile.setDescription(profileDtoModifyForm.getDescription());

    profileManager.save(profile);
```

the `profileManager.getById()` method  uses `org.Hibernate.Session.get()` method to get the object

the `profileManager.save()` methode uses `org.Hibernate.Session.save()`
But I was expecting an error since the object is already stored in database and has an id.

instead, hibernate performs an update:

```
Hibernate: update profile set description=?, name=? where id=?
```

then I don't understand the difference between save and saveOrUpdate methods...

afters some researchs about that, I found a lot of description. One says hibernate performs an update if id exists, an other says it should throws an error...

ps: I use Spring, if it changes something...

Comment: what is profileManager?

Comment: hum sorry, it's a service, the **profileManager.save()** only call **org.hibernate.Session.save()**

Comment: A save doesn't do anything if the object is already a hibernate managed instance. You are modifying a managed instance so as soon as the method ends (and I assume you have transactions setup) the method will do a commit on the transaction and the updates (yes updates) will be flushed and committed to the database. You could remove the save and it would still do the same.

Comment: ... that simple. that obvious. and I just didn't see it -_-

Ok, really thank you M.Deinum, I was going to search a long time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#save(java.lang.Object)) of the `Session.save` method you will see it talks about transient instances. This means non-hibernate managed entities. As you are doing a `Session.getById` to retrieve an object it is an **non**-transient instance.

If you would use a transient instance it indeed would leed to an exception stating that an object with the given identifier already exists. However as this already is a managed instances this is detected and instead of a save an update is issued.

To test this just create a new instance of the profile you want to save, give it an id that already exists in the database and try to store it.

On another note because it already is a managed intance you don't even need the call to `save` to have the changes persisted those will be automaticaly synchronized with the database.

The main difference between `save` and `saveOrUpdate` lies in the return type. When using `save` a newly created id is returned `saveOrUpdate` returns `void` (the same for `update`). But apart from that the internal code for storing the object in the database is the same regardless of the use of `save`, `update` or `saveOrUpate`.

Comment: indeed, that was still a little bit tricky for me. now I'm good with transient and persistent states

However, trying to save a new Profile with an id already used results in no error.

But that's probably besause I set a auto generated id strategy hum?